# Create email, save to draft after attachment has uploaded

Tags: vba, outlook

The following code loops through a folder, creates email with attachment and saves to draft.

```vb
Public Sub saveFileTodownload()

    Set draftItems = Outlook.Session.Folders("My Email").Folders("Drafts").Items

    strFile = Dir("d:\ga\localsdk\")

    Do While Len(strFile)
        Debug.Print strFile
        Set mail = draftItems.Add("IPM.NOTE")
        mail.Subject = "1downloadme" & Count
        mail.Attachments.Add ("d:\ga\localsdk\" & strFile)
        mail.Save
        strFile = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

I need to wait until the attachment has completely uploaded then call Save.

Is there any way to wait until the attachment has uploaded.

Note: If I debug it and wait a minute after the `Attachment.Add` line, the attachment has uploaded and Save works.

Comment: Please add 

    Option Explicit

and then define your variables. Then come back with proper code:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Do you think this will solve the problem? or you just want to leave somthing?

Comment: Do you think this will solve the problem? or you just want to leave somthing?

Comment: I positively believe people here are more willing to help you if they can try out runnable code, yes.

Answer (score 0):

`MailItem.Attachments.Add` is synchronous; by the time the call returns, the attachment is added to the message. What makes you believe this is not so?

Comment: Becouse this us what haopend to me. If I save the mail. it gives a message that atrachment still uploading and save will remove the attachment.

Comment: In outlook 2016 it dosnt give the message but the attachment keeps uploading. becouse i have 100 file to upload i need to wait till the attachment uploaded. or 100 will uploaded same time. which maks it verey slow

Comment: What message? "it gives a message that atrachment still uploading " - what does it mean? What method returns that error? Of course the whole message would still need to be uploaded to the server if you are using Exchange or IMAP4, but in the local store the message and the attachments are fine and accessible immediately after your code runs.

Comment: thats what i am talking about. i am using exhange server and i need to wait until attachment uploaded to the server then procceed with next email.

Comment: It is not the attachment, it is the whole message - attachments do not exist separately from their parent messages. You can force the sync using SyncObject.Start - it is asynchronous and you will need to wait for the SyncObject.SyncEnd event to fire. SyncObject can be retrieved from the Namespace.SyncObjects collection.

Comment: Or you can create the message in the online store to begin with by opening its parent folder in the online mode - but you will need Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or Redemption (any language) for that.

Comment: I am not familiar with synch. can you write me an example for the add attachment

Comment: Once again, there is nothing attachment specific here. The whole message would have to be uploaded, attachments or not. You just need to start the sync. Have you looked up the docs on MSDN?

Answer (score 0):

user93865

I tested your code and it works for me(No error message). However, it will be gets stuck if there are lots of attachments upload.

You could try this code :

```
Public Sub saveFileTodownload()
Dim store As Outlook.store
Dim space As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim folder As Outlook.folder
Set space = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set store = space.DefaultStore
Set folder = store.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts)
Set Item = folder.Items.Add("IPM.NOTE")
Item.Subject = "1downloadme"
Item.Body = "one"
Dim r As Long
r = 0
Do While r < 100
Item.Attachments.Add ("C:\Users\temp\Desktop\notes\abd.docx")
r = r + 1
Loop
'Item.Display
Item.Save
Item.Close
End Sub
```